# Marklogic : fetch word count from element word lexicons

Tags: marklogic

I have two sample XML file as following:

**abc.xml**

```
<data>
<text>i am a test user and doing testing here more and more. What are you doing?</text>
<data>
```

**def.xml**

```
<data>
<text>We are a doing nothing here you can say it time pass. what are you doing?</text>
<data>
```

Now I have created element word lexicons for `<text>` element. I am interested in following:

1. Getting all unique words and their count in the whole DB (having
   only above two files).
2. Getting all unique words for given files

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/lexicon#chapter

Comment: This whole link is talking about getting element/element-attribute value and their count (using cts:frequency) OR getting unique words etc but what i am looking for getting unique words and also occurrence of that word in a given uri or in whole DB.

Answer (score 1):

1) For all unique words and the number of matching fragments:

```
for $w in cts:element-words(xs:QName('text'))
return 
element word {
    attribute count { 
      xdmp:estimate(cts:search(doc(), cts:word-query($w))
    },
    $w }
```

That should be pretty quick, but to get the actual word count instead of just the fragment count, I think you may have to inspect each fragment, and this could get really slow:

```
sum(
  cts:search(doc(), cts:word-query($w))/cts:highlight(.,
    cts:word-query($w),<match/>)/count(//match)
  )
```

2) For all unique words per file:

```
for $d in doc()
return element file {
    for $w in cts:element-words(xs:QName('text'), (), (),
        cts:document-query(xdmp:node-uri($d))
    return element word { $w }
}
```

If you have the URI lexicon enabled, then you can further optimize 2) by iterating over `cts:uris()` instead of `doc()` and passing that value as the fourth argument to `cts:element-values()`, instead of calling `xdmp:node-uri` on the doc.

Comment: I tried to execute above query (Solution for 1) but it is giving me wrong result : <results warning="more than one root item">
  <word count="1">i am a test user and doing testing here more and more. What are you doing?</word> 
  <word count="1">We are a doing nothing here you can say it time pass. what are you doing?</word>
</results> what i am expecting here individual word count like in my case "where" 2 times "doing" 3 times etc

Comment: Are you sure you have an element word lexicon, not an element range index? Range indexes are value lexicons, not word lexicons, so they store the full value of each element, not the individual words. This is what your output suggests.

Comment: i had created both [element word lexicon and element range index] on it. i also tried by removing element range index on it but in that case your above query giving me error. since cts:element-values required element range index. Any one who can help me on this? not finding any optimized solution

Comment: @user1660340 Take a look at the updated solution. Using `cts:element-words` instead of `cts:element-values` should solve the problem.

Comment: I tried updated solution but getting count of all words as "0". :(

Comment: @user1660340 Sorry, `cts:frequency` only works with value lexicons, not word lexicons. You could quickly count the number of fragments containing a word, but I think unfortunately actually counting occurrences would be slow - you would have to actually count in each individual fragment. Take a look at the update for some ideas.